# Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

HTML Code

```
<table border="0px" id="map-flags" align="center">
<tr><td><img src="flags/ug.jpeg" alt="Welcome" width="160px" height="160px"></td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript Code

```
    <script>
        document.getElementbyId('tuts').addEventListener('click', function(e){
            console.log(e.toElement.alt);
        });
        
        
    </script>
```

Am trying to print out the Id in the Console but it brings this error, What could be the problem?

Comment: It's **getElementById** (**By** not **by**).

Comment: You don't have an element with an ID of tuts anywhere in that code

Answer (score 2):

Add an ID

```
<table border="0px" id="map-flags" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="tuts" src="flags/ug.jpeg" alt="Welcome" width="160px" height="160px">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and change getElementbyId to getElement**B**yId

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('tuts').addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.alt);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit: Change console.log(e.toElement.alt); to console.log(this.alt); **